# Run code on object change

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I want to run a piece of code everytime the active state changes. I store the value like:

```
export class AdminLayoutComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
activeState: string;
constructor(private router: UIRouter) {
    this.activeState = this.router.stateService.$current.name;
  }
}
```

How can I run a piece of code (that sets a class in the navigation menu for the active state) every time the current state changes?

Comment: What causes the state to change?

Comment: The user clicks on a uiSref link.

Comment: Why not add it as an additional function to the link?

Comment: Then you should simply be able to add an onClick listener, and run your logic there

Comment: I can't do that, because I have to be able to detect state change even if the user clicks on a uiSref link in any of the many child components.

Answer (score 0):

if several component change a "variable", the most easy is that the variable belong to a service. then, in your component use a

```
get variable(){
    return myservice.variable
}
set variable(value){
    myservice.variable=value
    ...addicional code when we change the variable... 
}
//So in your component you can use
    variable="HellowWord";
//Or in your .html
     {{variable}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [UI-Router](https://ui-router.github.io/) library?
In this case I guess you need to use [TransitionService](https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/docs/latest/classes/transition.transitionservice.html) hook.

```
export class AdminLayoutComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  activeState: string;

  constructor(private router: UIRouter) {
    this.activeState = this.router.stateService.$current.name;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.transitionService.onSuccess({}, (transition: Transition) => {
      this.activeState = this.router.stateService.$current.name;
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```